# How do I run a CSS Style change as soon as my page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my current code:

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="setActiveStyleSheet('blue'); return false;"><span class="pre-color-skin4"></span></a></li>
```

Basically when the user hits the button, blue happens.

However I want it so if the user loads a certain page of my website, this script is executed automatically as soon as the page loads/starts loading.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume from the tag on the question that you are using jquery. Then you can use the load() function.

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});
```

Comment: The style switcher is a javascript code however, so it doesn't work

Comment: jQuery is just a javascript library, so you can always call a javascript method from jQuery's load function. You would just have to include the jquery js file in your html page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried instead of .onClick to use .onLoad?

Here is a quick reference for your information.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `.ready()` it executes when the `DOM` is fully loaded.

For Eg:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     setActiveStyleSheet('blue'); //Call to your function   
});
```